# Does flagging off-topic flag as duplicate as well?

Tags: discussion, bug, flags

I flagged one post as being off-topic, and saying it rather belongs on Super User. However, on accident I clicked the flag button again, and this is what appeared:

[image]

I've only raised one flag: off-topic. However, why does the system think I have raised two flags? Is this a bug within the system?

Comment: Duplicate is a shortcut for one of the options under closing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're both the same type of flag in the sense with either choice you're asking that the question be closed. There's really no point in raising both of these flags because either way the result will be same, only the message on the closed question would be different.

So it doesn't think you've raised two flags, it thinks you've raised one flag of the same type as two of the options presented. If the system though you had raised two flags, it would say that you have 8 flags remaining instead of 9. Users are allowed to have 10 flags per day, plus 1 for every 10 net helpful flags and 1 for every 2000 reputation.

Comment: Technically, it's up to 10 *per day*, not active at once: not all that long ago (before flag aging got ramped up) I routinely had well over 100 pending. The absolute cap is 100/day.

Comment: Ah, ok. Updated my answer, thanks.